# Zend framework cli

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I have a question about the Zend framework. I want to include the main library of the zend framework in a php file and test the functions on the console. How can I do this simply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Zend framework 1, 2 & 3 you can use composer dependency manager.

I assume you have php installed already on your system.

Download [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar)

1) Create an empty folder and put composer.phar there.

2) Change to the created path in the console.

3) Run one of the commands below depending on which version you want to install.

Zend 1

- php composer.phar require zendframework/zendframework1

Zend 2

- php composer.phar require zendframework/zendframework:2.4.11

Zend 3

- php composer.phar require zendframework/zendframework:3.0.0

Create a script(e.g test.php) on the same folder with contents:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// put your code after
```

Run the script:

php test.php

Comment: thank you for your help. This is what i am looking for.