# ZF1 Aws S3 Bucket SDK availability

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

Is there a valid **Amazon S3 SDK for Zend Framework 1**. The existing SDK cannot use in ZF1 because ZF1 doesn't support namespaces. Is there a way to overcome this? I know there is an inbuilt service in ZF1 for S3 integration. But I wanted is a regularly updating S3 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

ZF1 does not use namespaces, but you can make it support them using the composer autoloader.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a composer.json in your project root directory with the following contents:

   {
       "require": {
           "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.36.9"
       }
   }
2. Download composer and run php composer.phar install in your root directory.
3. Require the composer autoloader in your **application/Bootstrap.php**:

   ```
   public function _initComposer()
   {
       require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
   }
   ```

   or add

   ```
   require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
   ```

   in your public/index.php.
4. Use the aws library:
   In your controller(or anywhere else you want to use it):

   ```
   // at the top of file.
   use Aws\S3\S3Client;
   ...
   // inside an action
   $s3 = new S3Client([
       'version' => 'latest',
       'region'  => 'us-west-2'
   ]);
   ```

### References

- [Composer zend1 framework with directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079525/composer-zend1-framework-with-directory-structure/45105423#45105423)
- [how to install zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753420/4448410)